# raster2pgsql: Argument list too long

Tags: postgis, postgresql, error, raster2pgsql

trying to insert rasters into my database. In sum, its about 870,000 files. Trying to do so with the following command

`raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M -F -l 8,16,32 *.jp2 public.sat| psql -d imagery -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres`

I get the following error message.

> -bash: /usr/bin/raster2pgsql: Argument list too long

What can I do? Does anyone already face the same issue? does anyone know a workaround. How to figure out, whats the maximum of files i can insert with one command?

Comment: `bash` expands items matching an `*` into the argument list - so effectively you are trying to execute a command with those 870k file names attached on the kernel. Use either a `for` loop, `find` (walks directories recusively!), or batch up the list of input raster files manually (`getconf ARG_MAX` may be of help, but really, manualy batching up the file list is the least favorable option...)

Comment: @geozelot in that case, a table need to be first prepared and secondly filled with data. e.g. `raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -p -M -F some_filename.jp2 public.sat|PGPASSWORD=password123 psql -d imagery -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres` and afterwards: `for fn in *.jp2; do raster2pgsql -s 4326 -a -I -M -F  $fn public.sat|PGPASSWORD=password123 psql -d imagery -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres; done`. But in this case overview maps are not possible anymore, or am I wrong?

Comment: unfortunately, the above solution gets very fast, very slow, even with out of db rasters.

Comment: I bet. Honestly, 870k rasters in PostGIS sounds like a terrible idea to me...but all I was saying above is that you are facing a `bash` specific issue.

Comment: what would be your suggestion for processing such a huge amount of rasters? Is there something with competitive functionality, but better working with 870k rasters?

Comment: Maybe you can try to merge your data in bigger chunks for example with GDAL (for example this dedicated tool: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html)

Comment: @robinloche good idea. I build several virtual rasters by utilizing gdalbuildvrt and used them to store the rasters in the db. Still filling the db,... seems to be faster now. But I thought about doing the processing in the fs instead of the db, might have less overhead as stated in several other comments in other questions here on the GIS stackexchange.